# Is it possible to default to with a checkbox input button?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a checkbox button asking for the user to select a genre, and I need to make it work so that if the user doesn't select a genre, the input automatically defaults to "other". Here is my code for the checkbox button:

```
checkboxGroupInput("select", label = h3("3. Select genre"), 
 choices = list('Action','Fantasy','Biography', 'Fantasy', 
                 'History', 'Musical', 'Reality TV', 
                 'Sport', 'War', 'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 
                 'Romance', 'Talk Show', 'Animation', 'Crime', 
                   'Game_show', 'Music', 'Film Noir', 'Horror', 
                  'Mystery', 'Western', 'Family', 'Sci Fi', 
                    'Thriller', 'News', 'Unknown', 'Other'), inline = TRUE),
```

Thank you

Comment: `checkboxGroupInput` has a parameter `selected`:  
The values that should be initially selected, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value in input type. See below.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="boxName" value="Other">
```